# Angularjs dynamically adding controls

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Im trying to adding dynamically $scope

```
    app.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function (html) {
            ele.html(html);
            $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
        });
    }
};});
```

and my HTML;

```
<select dynamic="myOption_{{ item.RowId }}" id="select_{{ item.RowId }}" multiple class="chosen" data-ng-model="selectedOption" data-placeholder="Select" data-ng-change="ChangeTopic()"
                    chosen="directiveOptions"
                    ng-options="item.Id as item.tag for item in optionsFromQuery"
                    style="width:100%;">
            </select>
```

angular;

```
    var appsx = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < result.item.length; i++) {
                var rowIds = parseInt(result.item[i].RowId);
                appsx = '<option value="" selected>' + result.item[i].Tags + '</option>';
                var controlName = 'myOption_' + rowIds;
                controlName = appsx;
            }
```

Example; if I try to $scope.myOption_100 = appsx; it's working but I cannot make dynamically scope

$scope.controlName = 'myOption_' + rowIds; like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try scope.$observe(attrs.dynamic.....

Comment: I fixed it now

    var appsx = '<option value="' + tagItem + '" selected="selected">' + tagItem + '</option>';
    var rowIds = parseInt(result.item[i].RowId);
    var controlName = 'myOption_' + rowIds;
    $scope[controlName] = appsx;